# Custom ModelValidatorProvider is not called in first request but works for all other requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to provide a feature in my application where error message which we are setting in Model should come from XML file placed in my project. To achieve this, I have created one class which extends DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider class and in that class, I have placed the code to read the error message from XML file. That class looks like below:

```
public class CustomDataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider : DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider
{
    #region Fields
    private readonly ICaching _cacheService;
    #endregion

    #region Ctor
    public CustomDataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider(ICaching cacheService)
    {
        this._cacheService = cacheService;
    }
    #endregion

    internal static ModelValidator Create(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, ValidationAttribute attribute)
    {
        return new DataAnnotationsModelValidator(metadata, context, attribute);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
    {
        List<ModelValidator> vals = base.GetValidators(metadata, context, attributes).ToList();

        var additionalValues = attributes.OfType<CustomisedAnnotationAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (additionalValues != null)
        {
            string _modelName = "";
            string _propertyName = "";

            if (metadata.ContainerType != null)
            {
                _modelName = metadata.ContainerType.Name;
                _propertyName = metadata.PropertyName;
            }

            if (metadata.IsRequired)
            {
                var valRequire = attributes.OfType<RequiredAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (valRequire != null) valRequire.ErrorMessage = CommonFunctions.GetMetadataFromXML("errorMessage", _propertyName, _modelName, "EN", valRequire.ErrorMessage, _cacheService);
            }

            var valCompare = attributes.OfType<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CompareAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (valCompare != null) valCompare.ErrorMessage = CommonFunctions.GetMetadataFromXML("compareErrorMessage", _propertyName, _modelName, "EN", valCompare.ErrorMessage, _cacheService);

            var valRegEx = attributes.OfType<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RegularExpressionAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (valRegEx != null) valRegEx.ErrorMessage = CommonFunctions.GetMetadataFromXML("regexErrorMessage", _propertyName, _modelName, "EN", valRegEx.ErrorMessage, _cacheService);

            var valRange = attributes.OfType<RangeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (valRange != null) valRange.ErrorMessage = CommonFunctions.GetMetadataFromXML("rangeErrorMessage", _propertyName, _modelName, "EN", valRange.ErrorMessage, _cacheService);

            var valCustomVal = attributes.OfType<CustomValidationAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (valCustomVal != null) valCustomVal.ErrorMessage = CommonFunctions.GetMetadataFromXML("customValErrorMessage", _propertyName, _modelName, "EN", valCustomVal.ErrorMessage, _cacheService);

        }

        return vals;
    }
}
```

In above code, `CommonFunctions.GetMetadataFromXML` function is responsible to read the relevant error message from XML.

After creating this class, I have registered this in `Global.asax` by writing following two lines of code:

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new CustomDataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider(container.Resolve<ICaching>()));
```

Now, problem which I am facing is, **when I run application first time, the error message which I have mentioned in my XML file are not being shown to user, instead, default MVC’s error message are being shown, but, on subsequent request, error message which I defined in my XML file are being shown.**

Could you please tell me what is the reason behind this behaviour? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding following line at the beginning of GetValidators() method, add that just before return statement

```
List<ModelValidator> vals = base.GetValidators(metadata, context, attributes).ToList();
```

So, after doing what I have mentioned above, this function will look like:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
    {
        var additionalValues = attributes.OfType<CustomisedAnnotationAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (additionalValues != null)
        {
            string _modelName = "";
            string _propertyName = "";

            if (metadata.ContainerType != null)
            {
                _modelName = metadata.ContainerType.Name;
                _propertyName = metadata.PropertyName;
            }

            if (metadata.IsRequired)
            {
                var valRequire = attributes.OfType<RequiredAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (valRequire != null) valRequire.ErrorMessage = CommonFunctions.GetMetadataFromXML("errorMessage", _propertyName, _modelName, "EN", valRequire.ErrorMessage, _cacheService);
            }

            var valCompare = attributes.OfType<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CompareAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (valCompare != null) valCompare.ErrorMessage = CommonFunctions.GetMetadataFromXML("compareErrorMessage", _propertyName, _modelName, "EN", valCompare.ErrorMessage, _cacheService);


            var valRegEx = attributes.OfType<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RegularExpressionAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (valRegEx != null) valRegEx.ErrorMessage = CommonFunctions.GetMetadataFromXML("regexErrorMessage", _propertyName, _modelName, "EN", valRegEx.ErrorMessage, _cacheService);

            var valRange = attributes.OfType<RangeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (valRange != null) valRange.ErrorMessage = CommonFunctions.GetMetadataFromXML("rangeErrorMessage", _propertyName, _modelName, "EN", valRange.ErrorMessage, _cacheService);

            var valCustomVal = attributes.OfType<CustomValidationAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (valCustomVal != null) valCustomVal.ErrorMessage = CommonFunctions.GetMetadataFromXML("customValErrorMessage", _propertyName, _modelName, "EN", valCustomVal.ErrorMessage, _cacheService);

        }

        List<ModelValidator> vals = base.GetValidators(metadata, context, attributes).ToList();

        return vals;
    }
```

This should work. Let me know if this doesn't solve your issue.